# Como puedo validar una matricula en un inicio de sesion si ya se ha registrado esa matricula previamente?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Este es mi dao

```
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface myDao {

    @Insert
    public void registrar(User user);

    @Query("select * from users")
    public List <User> getUsers();

}
```

Esta es mi base de datos

```
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)

public abstract class MyAppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract myDao myDao();

}
```

Esta es mi entidad

```
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int matricula;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    private String contrasenia;

    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getContrasenia() {
        return contrasenia;
    }

    public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) {
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }
}
```

Este es el metodo donde estoy haciendo el registro de usuarios y aqui es donde quiero que se valide si otra persona ingresa alguna matricula ya existente, se muestre un Toast que diga que ese usuario ya esta registrado, pero no se como acceder a las matriculas que estan guardadas en la base de datos, todo esto es el metodo donde cree la logica de los botones y el boton de registrar es donde guardo los nuevos usuarios, el primer if es donde verifico si los Edittext estan vacios, en eso no hay mucho problema ya que si funcionan, el else if es donde quiero hacer la validacion si la matricula que quieren registrar ya existe o no, y por ultimo el else es donde guardo los nuevos usuarios una vez que las condiciones anteriores se hayan validado

```
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        MatriculaRegistro = view.findViewById(R.id.Matricula_registrarse);
        PasswordRegistro = view.findViewById(R.id.contraseña_registrarse);

        btn_registrar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_registrarse_registrarse);
        btn_regresar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_regresar_registrarse);



        btn_registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(MatriculaRegistro.getText().toString().isEmpty() || PasswordRegistro.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Algun campo esta vacio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else if(){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El usuario ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    int matricula = Integer.parseInt(MatriculaRegistro.getText().toString());
                    String contrasenia = PasswordRegistro.getText().toString();

                    User user = new User();
                    user.setMatricula(matricula);
                    user.setContrasenia(contrasenia);
                    MainActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().registrar(user);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Usuario Registrado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    MatriculaRegistro.setText("");
                    PasswordRegistro.setText("");

                    navController.navigate(R.id.fragment_iniciar2);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Este es el if que verifica si los campos estan vacios

```
if(MatriculaRegistro.getText().toString().isEmpty() || PasswordRegistro.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Algun campo esta vacio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Aqui es donde quiero que se haga la validacion si ya exite la matricula que quieren ingresar

```
else if(MatriculaRegistro!=null){

         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El usuario ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

y con este else es donde se guarda el usuario()

```
else{
     int matricula = Integer.parseInt(MatriculaRegistro.getText().toString());
     String contrasenia = PasswordRegistro.getText().toString();

     User user = new User();
     user.setMatricula(matricula);
     user.setContrasenia(contrasenia);
     MainActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().registrar(user);

     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Usuario Registrado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     MatriculaRegistro.setText("");
     PasswordRegistro.setText("");

     navController.navigate(R.id.fragment_iniciar2);
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un `select` a la bd para que te devuelva las matriculas que estan almacenadas y despues compruebas si la que ingresa el usuario esta dentro de ese select.
Que base de datos estas usando ? porque no dejas las matriculas autoncrementales?

Comment: En mi clase estamos usando Dao ROOM y las matriculas no son autoincrementales ya que asi las pidio mi profesor

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear en tu DAO un método para verificar la existencia de registros.

Aquí lo haremos contando, el método devolverá `0` si no hay registros que cumplan el criterio:

Por ejemplo:

```
@Query("select count(*) from users where matricula =:matricula")
int countUser(int matricula);
```

Y para verificar:

```
int totalUsers = MainActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().countUser(MatriculaRegistro);

if(totalUsers==0) {
    //El registro no existe, puedes insertar
} else {
    //El registro existe
}
```

### Post-Data

Esta lógica puede ser trasladada al DAO, es decir, verificar desde el método `registrar()` si la fila existe antes de insertarla. También, puedes hacerlo de otro modo, mediante el uso de `OnConflictStrategy`. Para más detalles sobre esto, [consulta la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data).

Comment: Mil gracias, se agradece la ayuda!!!!